# What should I do if I was banned from reviewing suggested edits erroneusly?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review-suspension

I was banned for reviewing an edit that I think was an improvement (just as other two reviewers did). Well, now what should I do? Complain to moderators or ask for explanations or just wait silently until the ban ends? How can I improve from where I am? If I was not banned automatically but by somebody who thought that my approach to reviewing is wrong, I would like to know how was it wrong and how should I improve it but I do not see any other means except posting to meta.

[Here is the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12813079) that the system has mentioned as a reason for a ban:

Comment: Today's lesson is: *Do not waste everyone's time trying to salvage link-only answers*. Of course, it concerns editors, for reviewers it becomes: *Do not approve edits that waste everyone's time (including yours) trying to salvage link-only answers*.

Comment: I think this question would be better received if you changed it a little. Instead of assuming you got the review suspension erroneously, I'd ask where your reviewing is different from what the moderators desire.

Comment: There's a difference between salvaging and polishing, @FrédéricHamidi. If a link-only answer can be turned into a real answer, I'd love to see that as an edit. This appeared to only polish the post though, not salvage it.

Comment: @hichris, it's a fine line. I assume you're referring to turd polishing, which is indeed the case here (late, link-only answer). However, IMHO link-only answers are extremely hard to even salvage -- even if you take the time to transfer the *exact* pieces of information from the link that address the question, others have to spend approximately the same time to validate it. Such answers are also usually posted under poor questions, so it is only rarely worth it, again, IMHO.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi True, but it is occasionally worth it. I saw a post on rPi.SE a few days ago which was link-only, but happened to exactly solve my issue. So, I suggested an edit to make the content self-contained.

Comment: @hichris123 You still shouldn't replace the link with an answer; post an answer and flag the non-answer instead!

Comment: Why in the world did you think that a link to the OSI model in Hindi was a useful answer on an English language site?

Comment: @BilltheLizard, I do not know, maybe because I do not want to hurt people based on their ethnicity, the guy still seemed on topic and seemed wanted to be helpful to the OP.

Comment: @exebook Him being possibly indian might make him being able to adequately speak english less likely, but this site is still exclusively english, and that's in no way a bad thing (I'm not a native english speaker). There are other sites catering to other audiences...

Comment: How is posting a link to a Hindi site at all helpful to the OP, [Adam Davis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2915/adam-davis)? This isn't about being hurtful to people who aren't native English speakers, it's about not perpetuating noise for *everyone else*.

Answer (score 22):

The review you refer to is not an audit, so you have apparently gotten a manual review suspension from a moderator.

Looking at it now, we see that both the post and the user account have been deleted. It looks like the original post was just a user spamvertizing their website. The edit suggestion was polishing the spam post. This would explain the review suspension - you thought you were helping someone make a post more acceptable, but you were indirectly helping a spammer.

For reviewing in general, there is some [guidance on reviewing edits on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155539/168333).

Going over your recent reviews, I think a few of your other Approvals should have been Rejected instead.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12813082 : adding code or a code example to an answer is questionable. The editor is putting words in the answerers mouth. This should have been a comment.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12806929 : any edit that merely puts some **words** or **parts of sentences** in boldface are pointless. There have been a number of posts on Meta complaining about this type of edit.

There are a few more, and we could discuss them if you like.

As a general rule - when in doubt, <kbd>Skip</kbd>.