# I'm banned from review. What should I have done instead?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, review-suspension

I am banned from review. No problem, but I want to learn from my mistake so that I won't do the wrong thing again in the future.

Ban message:

> Your review on https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14965119 wasn't helpful; please review the history of the post and consider how choosing a different action could've helped achieve that outcome more quickly.

Come back in 7 days to continue reviewing.

When I reviewed that tag wiki edit earlier, I rejected it with:

> This edit copies a significant amount of content from an external source. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating something [useful to this community *specifically*](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/), and be sure to attribute the original author. See: [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

but it was later approved (Approve × 3, Reject × 2).

I have checked [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6529557/revisions) and I can see that the edit has been rolled back.

I have searched [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) but I can't find similar ban messages.

I have checked other posts related to review ban like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341306/reason-for-review-ban), [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341327/banned-for-failing-to-recognize-check-for-plagiarism-1st-time-draconian), [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341757/something-wrong-with-the-review-path), [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338658/blocked-from-reviews-because-my-review-was-approved), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287550/review-ban-reason-and-warnings), [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338605/do-all-incorrect-reviews-trigger-a-suspension), [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338035/edit-review-ban-why), [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326876/what-should-i-do-if-i-was-banned-from-reviewing-suggested-edits-erroneusly), and many more, but they seem different from my case.

My questions are:

1. What does *"that outcome"* in the ban message refer to?
2. What *"different action"* should I take instead?

- Approve the edit?
- Reject the edit with another reason?
- Skip the review?
- Flag the edit?
- Anything else?

Comment: I think it was a mistake. I would have rejected it too.

Comment: I suspect a moderator simply banned the wrong user by accident. Shall we start a betting pool on *which* moderator it was? ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker we need a wheel of blame with SO moderators!

Comment: @Braiam Maybe if we can find someone who can program computers and such we can make a website for that. Do you maybe know someone who could do that? Or perhaps we can do it ourselves if we can find a website that will help us out.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker https://jsfiddle.net/Ldvwp8uv/12/embedded/result/ just use moderators.

Comment: As @dorukayhan alluded to but didn't actually say: Later reviewers will see your review message, and naming the source where things were copied from is quite helpful to them.

Comment: Oh, that was a prepackaged reason you picked.  Hmm.  Maybe we need a feature request to allow adding a URL when picking that reason.

Comment: I was there when this happened. Was only a matter of time before it came up (Pang, review banned?). Time to spin the wheel of blame...

Comment: TURN, Fortune, turn thy wheel, and lower the proud;
Turn thy wild wheel thro’ sunshine, storm, and cloud;
Thy wheel and thee we neither love nor hate.

Turn, Fortune, turn thy wheel with smile or frown;
With that wild wheel we go not up or down;
Our hoard is little, but our hearts are great.

Smile and we smile, the lords of many lands;
Frown and we smile, the lords of our own hands;
For man is man and master of his fate.

Turn, turn thy wheel above the staring crowd;
Thy wheel and thou are shadows in the cloud;
Thy wheel and thee we neither love nor hate.

Tennyson, 1859

Comment: @BoltClock, can you give the guilty moderator a meta-review ban, that is, ban them from reviewing reviews?

Comment: @Robert Columbia: Not without prying their diamond out of their cold, dead hands. (In other words, no, mods can't relieve other mods of mod abilities, not even with a suspension.)

Comment: @Braiam Here https://jsfiddle.net/v9jcr0gy/1/embedded/result/

Comment: While Brad has summed it up accurately as "this is the exact opposite of what was intended" - and my fellow mods have corrected it (embarrassing enough in itself) - I embarrassingly admit this was my mistake. I clicked "ban all rejecters" instead of "ban all approvers". Also, have to agree with the moderators that've commented on Brad's answer - you're a fantastic person on the site. I just hope that my hiccough doesn't  discourage you from further participation.

Comment: The other half of the query "What should I have done instead", is grammatically incorrect and is mentally bothering me each time i try to look or read it :(

Comment: @IteratioN7T There is nothing grammatically incorrect about "What should I have done instead?" Are you thinking that it should be written, "What should have I done instead?"? That would *not* be correct. The (pro)noun always goes after the verb "should".

Comment: You should run for a mod position the next election.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

It's pretty clear this is the exact opposite of what was intended, so I've lifted your ban and the one for the other rejecting reviewer here. My guess is that a moderator userscript went haywire.

I found two separate serial plagiarists based on your flags alone in just the last day, and I'm pretty sure you're the best flagger in the history of the site, so it's safe to say you know what you're doing.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is that quantitative or qualitative?

Comment: *"I'm pretty sure you're the best flagger in the history of the site"* Dang, good on you, @Pang! Thank you, and keep up the good work!

Comment: [48,462 helpful flags](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1402846/pang?tab=topactivity), not the worst flagger indeed (@Qix looks like quantitative)

Comment: Qix: you don't get to be a quantative flagger without a reasonably high standard of quality. Pang has the quality down to a T, *and* flags in quantity. He's got competition on the quantity side, but as far as quality goes is nigh faultless.

Comment: @gnat: rejection rate ~0.1%. Qualitative.

Comment: @MartijnPieters 99,9% acceptance rate? _Damn_, thats impressive.

Comment: @gnat Oh man I looked for it but didn't see it. That _is_ impressive.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I wasn't criticizing, I was just curious if it was because a small number of quality flags, or a high volume of flags - namely because I couldn't find the count. Looks like it's the best of both.

Comment: @Cody Gray: You just posted that comment so you could make that rhyme, didn't you?

Comment: When you see that the flagger is Pang, Down comes the diamond hammer with a bang. I don't know if you all sang, But hey, I can make a song, DANG!

Comment: @BhargavRao you're a poet and didn't know it? :p

Comment: @gnat Pang isn't the most prolific flagger. [Andy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/189134/andy?tab=topactivity) has 109,000 helpful flags (although a lot of them are [automated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280546)).

Comment: @yellowantphil - I regard post and comment flags differently. 102000 of Andy's flags are comment flags, where only 2000 of Pang's are. There's quite a difference in value between flagging a "thanks" comment and non-answers or spam. Not that what Andy's working on isn't of value, but Pang's identification of tens of thousands of non-answers has had a much larger material impact on site quality.

Comment: Keep up the awesome work Pang!

Comment: Given these comments, I'm greatly entertained that Pang's next reputation threshold is "access moderator tools". Maybe an accepted flag should incur a reputation boost similar to an upvote?

Comment: @ceejayoz I believe he's got [two most powerful moderation tools](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268115/839601) already

Comment: @gnat Certainly. It was just pretty funny to go from this to their profile and see that tracking as the next reputation threshold.