# Looking for some statistics about users who regularly bump into close votes limit

Tags: support, vote-to-close, statistics

I would want to learn more about folks who regularly (say, 20-25% of total days visited last year) cast 47-50 close votes a day.

<sup>(Number 47 above was picked because at one of related discussions some people mentioned that they stop voting at 2-3 votes left in order to make sure that they aren't out of votes in case if some extraordinary awful question pops up.)</sup>

---

How many of such folks are there (say, for last 365 days)? How many of their votes are cast from the review queue and outside of it? How many of these folks have tag badges and what is percentage of votes cast by these badge holders in their tags?

I am also interested in stats of how their votes work. How many of the questions they voted on end up closed, deleted, and deleted without close by a [30-days roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/165773)? How many end up staying open with positive score?

I expect requested stats to help me better understand how to address concerns about bad questions hanging open for too long.

Related discussions:

- [We need more close votes!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285486/839601)
  <sup>(answer there has related stats but not as detailed as I would want to)</sup>
- [Is using reputation to scale the number of close votes the best way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281985/165773)
- [Empowering tag-badge holders part II - let's look at silver?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240702/165773)

Comment: Also some stats on folks who use 90+ flags per day to see, who all trouble us mods, the most ;)

Comment: @BhargavRao [tag:no-plz] don't reveal us mass flaggers `: (`

Comment: @BhargavRao just suspend [Pang](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342205/im-banned-from-review-what-should-i-have-done-instead#comment436900_342207 "'48,462 helpful flags...'") and your trouble is over :)

Comment: Good idea, thinking of suspending the top few [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6083410#6083410) :D

Comment: 3rd in your list has particularly suspicious username "Community", must be someone's sock puppet @BhargavRao

Comment: Wow, interesting. The UI actually *allows* moderators to suspend Community (and even delete it). Wonder if anyone has actually done that though (for science, at least).

Comment: "this looks like a beginning of a new beautiful" experiment @BhargavRao - folks are already asking for it: [Give Community ♦ a review ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209349/165773)

Comment: Voting to close

Comment: why, aren't you out of votes here yet @DanBeaulieu

Comment: "How many of the questions they voted on end up closed, deleted, and deleted without close by a 30-days roomba? How many end up staying open with positive score?" To get a meaningful result there you would probably want to gauge that with the values for all users including those not hitting the limit (like me).

Comment: @Trilarion I limited this request to most basic stats because without knowing these it is hard to tell what else is important. For example if there are, say, only 20-30 users having this issue, I would be first interested to learn something other than how their votes compare to the rest. If on the other hand there are 200-300 such folks then yes I would be much interested to learn how their votes stand in comparison