# Can I nominate someone else to be a moderator?

Tags: support, moderators, moderator-election

## I'd like to nominate [Pang](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1402846/pang) to be a moderator.

This user is already doing the job of a moderator with the tools available. The current moderators also highly respect this user. Here is what the moderators say about Pang:

*(quotes taken from [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342205/im-banned-from-review-what-should-i-have-done-instead))*

### [Brad Larson ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342207/3681880)

> I found two separate serial plagiarists based on your flags alone in
> just the last day, and I'm pretty sure you're the best flagger in the
> history of the site, so it's safe to say you know what you're doing.

[and](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342205/im-banned-from-review-what-should-i-have-done-instead#comment437141_342207)

> I regard post and comment flags differently. 102000 of Andy's flags
> are comment flags, where only 2000 of Pang's are. There's quite a
> difference in value between flagging a "thanks" comment and
> non-answers or spam. Not that what Andy's working on isn't of value,
> but Pang's identification of tens of thousands of non-answers has had
> a much larger material impact on site quality.

### [Martijn Pieters ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342205/im-banned-from-review-what-should-i-have-done-instead#comment436920_342207)

> you don't get to be a quantative flagger without a reasonably high
> standard of quality. Pang has the quality down to a T, and flags in
> quantity. He's got competition on the quantity side, but as far as
> quality goes is nigh faultless.

[and](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342205/im-banned-from-review-what-should-i-have-done-instead#comment436923_342207)

> rejection rate ~0.1%. Qualitative.

### [Bhargav Rao ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342205/im-banned-from-review-what-should-i-have-done-instead#comment436941_342207)

> When you see that the flagger is Pang,
> Down comes the diamond hammer with a bang.
> I don't know if you all sang,
> But hey, I can make a song, DANG!

### [Jon Clements ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342205/im-banned-from-review-what-should-i-have-done-instead#comment437047_342205)

> ... Also, have to agree with the moderators that've commented on
> Brad's answer - you're a fantastic person on the site.

## Nominating other people?

Based on Pang's history and the moderator comments, I think this user would be a great addition to the moderator team. Pang could be even more effective given more powerful tools.

However, I'm not Pang and it looks like all of [the other nominations](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) are self-nominations. Is it possible for me to nominate Pang? Or if you see this, Pang, would you nominate yourself?

Comment: See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft_(politics)

Comment: Just to clarify, this is a `support` tag, not a `feature-request`.

Comment: Yes, just pointing out that that terminology is sometimes used for this kind of request

Comment: @EJoshuaS, your comment clarification about terminology was helpful. My comment above was not meant to be a reply to you, but to the downvoters. I intended for my post to be an encouragement for Pang to run, but I mistakenly framed it as a question about nominating (drafting?) other people. I assume the downvoters are taking it as a feature request.

Comment: I didn't know about the self-nomination-only policy, and this question helped me discover the answer quickly through searching Meta. I think it should stick around, even if the specifics become outdated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No; we want a user to nominate themselves to show that *they* are committed to the role. If they get nominated — and elected — against their will, and they decide they don't want to accept the role at the end of the election, they'd have to withdraw, thus creating work in deciding who should take their place (usually this entails deferring to the next best candidate, but it isn't always as simple and straightforward).

Some candidates might appreciate others nominating for them, but remember that being a moderator is a huge responsibility. We want to make sure that every candidate is committed. Furthermore, although a candidate can withdraw themself at any time, we want to make this opt-in, not opt-out. Otherwise, there would be far too many users being nominated against their will and having to opt out.

If you feel strongly that a candidate should run, let them make the decision to do so. If they are unsure how to write their nomination, that's something you can help with, but ultimately it is still their nomination and they are still the one running.

Pang is without a doubt *the* best flagger in the entire history of the site, but if they are content with the tools that they have and believe that they are most effective that way, that's their choice, and we're more than happy to keep things the way they are.