# Something should be done about bad reviewers

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits

So, I was gaining reputation by posting edits. As you can see from my profile, I've no upvotes on my questions nor answers. :-) My [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19746655). I always edit carefully, I know the strict requirements of Stack Overflow and I'm always aware of them when editing posts. As a result, you'll be able to see that I've `17` edit suggestions approved and `0` rejections.

A few days ago, as usual, I edited a post that has some sort of code but not-formatted. I edited it and formatted it.

> Commented: improved formatting

Was approved by two people, but rejected by one who had only one review, of my edit, a rejection. (Till then when I first saw this.)

He wrote:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits
>   that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of
>   the post's owner.

An edit which is commented as `improved formatting` must not have a great and wonderful, drastic change as usual. I think, he though himself as `GOD` getting the power to review after spending some time on Stack Overflow to earn reputations.

IF he's right, are they, the two, wrong?

They had reputation like his, one more than him.

How can we differ good and bad reviews?

[image: Review example]

Comment: Please, for God's sake, don't go to my profile and downvote questions/answers. I promise they're there only to improve this community.

Comment: Ow and instead of going to your profile and downvoting all your questions/answers I just downvoted this one because of [the lack of free hand circles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/down-votes/info), it suddonly dissapeared when I was reading it the first time, I didn't have any coffee in the last hour, it won't affect your rep, your first comment, and other reasons :) <--- mandatory smiley

Comment: @Toaster: I fail to see the problem. Different people see things differently. The person who voted to reject thought that your added sentence deviated from the question. That's why we require multiple people to review edits rather than just allowing one person to have that power alone.

Comment: The addition of the word "Job" in your edit might have been what caused the reject vote. Not being too familiar with the subject, I would have a hard time determining if that was a good edit or not. The rest of the edit looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: The bigger issue I see is that you posted the same answer to multiple questions. And it links to a library that you authored, and you failed to disclose that fact in your answers. Looks like spam to me.

Comment: The question may be different, but thinking in my way would help both of them. so I did that.

Comment: Have you received so many downvotes since you asked this meta question? The Meta effect is a real thing, but the nature of this concern makes it seem like inappropriate targeting is taking place.

Comment: @E_net4 It looks more like downvotes have been given due to the spammy/duplicate nature of the contributions by the asker.

Comment: FWIW, when reading this Meta post I was initially very confused by your insertion of the title into the question body.  I didn’t read the title (because it’s rarely useful when reviewing suggest edits), so it looked like you were trying to “hijack” the question by adding a question of your own (which people try to do sometimes).  I’m guessing this is why the reviewer rejected your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been [pointed out by user NobodyNada](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368086/something-should-be-done-about-bad-reviewers#comment590957_368086), the reviewer may have thought that you were trying to hijack the question.

There are a few other things I'd like to point out.

First, the Reject reason that the reviewer used is a canned comment - they didn't type this in, they just chose an option that automatically adds this as a comment.

Second, a few points about the use of capitalization and markdown. "So, What does ..." - the "What" should not have been capitalized.
In your post here, you've used `code markdown` for things that aren't code. Please don't, code markdown is for code and technical artifacts like file names. It's not for emphasis, we have **boldface** and *italics* for that. (And please use emphasis only when it's really, really, really necessary!)

You used the edit summary to clarify your intentions - "improved formatting". Great! That helps reviewers and the OP  of the edited post to understand the purpose of your edit. In this case, maybe you could have said a little more - "included question from title into post", or something like that.

Editing can be hard, even more for users who aren't native English speakers. Don't take Rejects as an offense, or as some kind of power game. Instead, think of them as learning opportunities.

On closing, I'm glad to hear you say that you edit carefully, and that you do your best to meet the high standards that this site has. Keep that up!

Comment: From where I can know about doing good-quality edits? and what i have to follow to do that?

Comment: If I get -20 votes in one meta-question... and **I've to delete my own relevant questions and answers that help the community,  from main profile due to thunderbolt of downvotes..**, isn't that enough cause to have a bad impression about high-reputation holders? Shoudn't I think that they don't want to me to get reps? 

I asked a bad-meta question and you downvote me. It's okay till then. But, you go to my own profile and force me to delte all helpful questions/answers , it isn't okay (Here, you doesn't mean you).

:-)

Comment: Votes on Meta don't affect your reputation. People do vote a lot here on Meta, both up and down. You're having a rough start here, but you're not alone in that. It does help to assume good intentions, and take a modest attitude. As an example - [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342205/812149) is an old question asked by a user with about 6k points, who got banned from review. The user didn't accuse people, but instead asked what he/she had done wrong, and what he/she should have done differently. It shows that even users with thousands of points, benefit from staying modest here.

Comment: Oops, he did my edit review a few days ago. **I know about meta-votes, I saw them**, but I'm trying to say that **the people go to my main profile and then downvote relevant questions/answers**.

_I agree, without vote system the community would become ugly_

.But, that doesn't mean one to force delete my good work by downvotes

And, I'm not a native English speaker, I'm a Bengali

Answer (score 2):

The idea I assume is always a "majority wins" system. Yes he did reject the edit but two other people approved it. This meant it was in turn approved and the edit was made. You shouldn't necessarily care about what the minority say and obviously the voting system doesn't care either. It takes the majority because it's likely they are right. If the person who rejected has anything more to say as to why it should be they can flag it (?) and say there.

tl;dr, majority is correct however minority shouldn't necessarily be ignored

Comment: I was far from serious about that. I'd get the ban hammer for that

Answer (score 0):

First, note that if your edit was Accepted then the one Reject doesn't negatively impact you at all. Your edit still gets applied and you still get +2 reputation points. So you weren't harmed by this review.

Second, I agree with picciano that the addition of "Job" is likely what caused the one Reject because your edit summary doesn't explain why you added it. Ideally, your edit comment will explain *all* of your changes or at least the changes that aren't self-explanatory.

> but rejected by one who had only 1 reviews

This means they're new to reviewing. It's much more likely that they just made a mistake than that they have a G-d complex. And it's because we're all fallible humans that the system requires two reviewers to agree (unless the reviewer chooses to edit it themselves).