# Not clear why 'needs author edit' was not correct for a question in triage with no code

Tags: support, triage, review-suspension, specific-audit

I encountered the following triage audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/28178676

What I did

- I looked into the text and searched for a question. It was there. Passed.
- How was the question taken by the community? A vote of 6 may hint the question is okay.
- I searched for code-snippets or something programming-related. Didn't pass.
- I looked into the comments and found also queries for something code-related. I was supported.

I decided to choose the 'needs author edit' option.

Now my decision led to a review ban. But to be honest I still think my decision was correct.

I've read the following questions but they did not clarify the problem with this option to me:

- [Why was I suspended from reviewing for selecting "Requires Editing" in Triage?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389148/why-was-i-suspended-from-reviewing-for-selecting-requires-editing-in-triage)
- [I'm banned from review. What should I have done instead?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342205/im-banned-from-review-what-should-i-have-done-instead)

On a side-note: The text in the suspension says 'We suspect that you are not actually reviewing the tasks.'. Well, that is a bad assumption. I take this very seriously and spend quite a lot of my spare time on helping to improve Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is asking us to be nice to new contributors which is absolutely correct. But I ask Stack Overflow to be nice to the people who work for free to improve the site too. If I made a mistake, okay, but there should be an explanation of what was wrong and some help provided to keep me motivated to spend my spare time again in future.

Comment: Relevant: [How does the Triage review queue work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295650/11682469)

Comment: Minor point. The suspension text doesn't say "We *assume* that you are not ...". It says "We *suspect* that you are not ..." which is a different thing.

Comment: @JeanneDark I don't understand why this is a duplicate of the target you're suggesting. This is about a different question, isn't it?

Comment: Do not judge questions based on the comments. If you **know** the question needs an edit from the author, click that button. If you only suspect so (lack of a “code snippet” is not a close reason), just skip.

Comment: Relevant: [There is no shame in using “Skip”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/11682469)

Comment: As far as I can see, this question **does** lack a MRE. Afaik, op's decision was correct.

Comment: @MikeS. I see what you mean if the OP is asking about dealing with the review ban. My reading of the question is that the OP wants feedback on the specific audit, in which case the duplicate target doesn't seem appropriate to me. I could be misunderstanding the intent of the question though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm of the view that [if your question doesn't contain code it probably doesn't belong here](https://old.reddit.com/r/programming/), but note the "probably".

The reason I stand behind this statement is because **code is context**. So many questions waffle on about what they're trying to do, and how it hasn't worked, and various other things, and I'm just like... dude, if you'd shown us the code instead of doing a poor job of describing the problem, we would've been able to help you. Instead I have no idea what your problem is, so I have to vote to close this question, which helps neither of us.

But in this case, while the question lacks code, its context is very clear (though perhaps not at a glance): the author updated their Java version on Linux and now their tests fail (and potentially their codebase is broken) because the new version extends the precision of the `Instant` class from micro- to nanoseconds, and they're looking for a simple way to avoid having to update their codebase to account for this change (maybe there's a command-line compatibility switch for the JVM that they aren't aware of, for example).

It's a completely clear question, it's objectively about programming, it shows research (the OpenJDK bug report), and it would have very specific answers if what's being asked for is possible. It is, in fact, a sterling example of a good question.

Thus, I believe your audit was incorrect. Whether the system was correct for review-banning you is beyond my capabilities to determine, but I will note that bans are not issued for single incorrect audits, or else pretty much everyone would've been banned at some stage.

Answer (score 11):

> I searched for [...] something programming-related. Didn't pass.

Explain to me how the problem statement

> *the system clock to nanosecond precision [...] is incompatible with the TIMESTAMP limitations in Postgres.*

isn't something programming related? Last time I checked Java was no longer a niche language and PostgreSQL is a rather successful open source [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system).

Then the question continues to explain that a certain type behaves differently based on the target OS. Tests are failing. That is a lot of signal to indicate we are dealing with a programming problem here.

They found they could resolve their issue by truncating their precision, but they are looking for an option that doesn't involve fiddling with the precision. Again, that sounds like a programming problem to me.

Not all questions need code. That question is an example. Sharing the unit test would have had so little added value. Insisting on adding it is busy work.

The question is clear and understandable as it is, and no edits are needed, by anyone. Clicking <kbd>Skip</kbd> or <kbd>Looks OK</kbd> are the appropriate review actions.

Comment: I don't fully subscribe to the idea that the code is not necessary. Too often do I see problems (in Java-land) after upgrading because the code was pretty much always wrong, but older versions of APIs might have been more lenient and would automatically rectify the mistake. This is especially true for Hibernate, but I've seen it in other places as well.

Comment: @Gimby I can live with a partial subscription ... points taken.